# Get specific column header names from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I need to get a specific column header name based on value.

For ex: I am using the below query to get list of column headers and it works fine and on top of this can I get column names which has specific name like `Department` alone.

**LINQ**

```
string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                         .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                         .ToArray();
```

How can I add contains or exists to this query to get specific columns.

Comment: You mean like adding `.Where(x => x == "Department")`?

Comment: @DavidG `x` is `DataColumn`. How is that possible? Probably you mean `.Where(x => x.ColumnName == "Name")`. Check my answer.

Comment: @S.Akbari Not if you put that line after the `Select`. I didn't answer this question because it's unclear and rather pointless to select a single string from a list of strings when you already have the string. I wish other people had thought the same...

Comment: @DavidG Yes by putting `Where` after `Select` it works and I also have pointed this. I thought you said replace `Select` with `Where`.

Comment: @S.Akbari And nothing to say about the second part of my comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a filter, like this:

```
string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                             .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                             .Where(x => x == "Department")
                             .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> containsKeys = new List<string>();
containsKeys.Add("SomeWildCard");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                             .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                             .ToArray().Where(t => containsKeys.Contains(t)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either select then filter the result:

```
.Select(x => x.ColumnName).Where(c => c == "Department")
```

Or first filter then select:

```
.Where(x => x.ColumnName == "Department").Select(c => c.ColumnName)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Columns` property is of type `DataColumnCollection`, which has an indexer `public DataColumn this[string name]` to get DataColumn by name:

```
DataColumn dc = dt.Columns["Department"];
```

to get multiple columns by name use `Select()` with indexer:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Department", "Something" };
DataColumn[] columns = names.Select(name => dt.Columns[name]).ToArray();
```